# "A resource exists with a different case" exception when synchronizing Gradle project with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, buildship

When importing Gradle project to eclipse using Eclipse's native buildship plugin the import fails with the following exception:

> org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.GradlePluginsRuntimeException:
> org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: A resource
> exists with a different case: '/gui'.     at
> org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.workspace.DefaultWorkspaceOperations.renameProject(DefaultWorkspaceOperations.java:361)
> at
> org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.workspace.ProjectNameUpdater.updateProjectName(ProjectNameUpdater.java:49)
> at
> org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.workspace.SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.synchronizeOpenWorkspaceProject(SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.java:159)
> at
> org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.workspace.SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.addExistingEclipseProjectToWorkspace(SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.java:189)
> at
> org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.workspace.SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.synchronizeNonWorkspaceProject(SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.java:177)
> at
> org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.workspace.SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.synchronizeGradleProjectWithWorkspaceProject(SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.java:130)
> at
> org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.workspace.SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation$1.run(SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.java:85)
> at
> org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2380)
> at
> org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2400)
>
> .... etc
>
> Caused by: java.lang.Exception: A resource exists with a different
> case: '/gui'.     at
> org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException.provideStackTrace(ResourceException.java:42)
> at
> org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException.(ResourceException.java:38)

This probably has something to do with the project Gui that I have in the directory structure.
It used to work just fine for years though. Commit history does not show anything relevant (no changes to Gui project or any Gradle-related files).

Does anyone have an idea of what could be causing it or how to investigate this problem further?

Tried to install newest eclipse and import freshly checked out projects directory structure. Did not help.
Renaming "Gui" project to something else or changing it to "gui" causes lots of issues with other projects which refer to it.

*Edit
I found the problem:

build.gradle file in the gui project used to have the following lines:

```
eclipse {
    project {
        name = 'somename'
    }
}
```

and these lines were apparently renaming the project from Eclipse prospective to 'somename'. Removing the lines started to cause naming conflict with another project called Gui located at a different level.

Comment: The exception is saying there is already a project called `gui` (all lower case). A project called `Gui` (just differing in case) is not allowed. Depending on the OS and file system resources just differing in case may not be allowed.

Comment: There is indeed another project gui on a different level. Directory structure looks like this:
TopLvlDir {gui, SecondLvlDir{Gui, ...}}.

This however was the case for years and never caused any synchronization issues whatsoever.
Something must have changed so this started to be a problem.
Setting aside the question of the validity of having two directories called gui at different levels in the directory structure what exactly might have changed so it started to matter?

Comment: Also, please note, this is a production directory structure in a large company and everything builds just fine by any other means except Eclipse so this must be a buildship issue, not the problem with the project structure. Having said that if some change in the project structure caused eclipse build to fail I want to know what that might be.

Comment: I don't use gradle so I can't comment on that, but the `ResourceException` message is from Eclipse code being called by the gradle plug-in. I checked the Eclipse source code and the only reason I can see for that message is what I said - two projects with a name only differing by case.